# Looking for APTonCD equivalent for Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: aptoncd

Is there an equivalent of APTonCD for Ubuntu Server (12.04) edition ?

If not, can I use a local repository cread by APTonCD (using a Desktop edition) and use it from Ubuntu Server 12.04 edition ? If yes, how ?

Comment: What makes you think you can't use APTonCD on the server?

Comment: Because on Desktop Edition you must use the Synaptic Manager to use the image file created by APTonCD, and there is no graphic stuff like that on a Server edition

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, it is indeed a GUI program. Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? What packages do you want to make available and what is your final objective? If you want to install packages with no internet access for example, there are other tools for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will expand this if you explain exactly what you need to do but to answer the question you asked, yes it is possible to use an image created by `aptoncd` with Ubuntu Server.

If you have access to a GUI Ubuntu Create the image file using the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/APTonCD) on your Desktop install.

#### A. If your server has a CD drive

1. Burn the image to a CD (you can do this using `aptoncd`) and put the CD in your server's drive.
2. Open a terminal and run

   ```
   sudo apt-cdrom add
   ```
3. Update your sources list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

#### B. If your server has no CD drive

If you don't have a CD drive on your server, you will need to mount the image file and then add that.

1. Copy the image file (something like `aptoncd-20140505-CD1.iso`) to your server.
2. Mount the image somewhere

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/foo
   sudo mount -o loop /path/to/aptoncd-20140505-CD1.iso /media/foo
   ```
3. Run `apt-cdrom` again but telling it not to attempt to detect the CD automatically, nor to mount it (`-m`) and specifying the mount point (`-d`) as `/media/foo`:

   ```
   sudo apt-cdrom --no-auto-detect -md /media/foo add
   ```
4. Update your sources list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```